# Find uplay, Origin, Battle.net game ID

Tags: pc, origin, battle.net, ubisoft-connect

Through [this](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/1379491-Uplay-exe-and-commands-parameters-Forums+) forum I found out that you can make uplay start a game with the following command. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ubisoft\Ubisoft Game Launcher\Uplay.exe" "uplay://launch/410/0"` This specific command wil launch Rayman Legends.

My guess is that the game ID for Rayman Legends is 410 and so this command should also work for other Uplay games. Is there a way to easily find out the uplay game ID's?

## Update:

I am working on a system which can creates a game library of all games I own on steam, uplay, origin and battle.net (in the future I might want to add the windows store games). The library then starts the games using a commands. Here are some examples:

#### Uplay: (Explaned by @Experimental_Rocket)

`"Uplay.exe" "uplay://launch/410/0"`

#### Steam:

`steam.exe -applaunch 280`

I want to create this method instead of just creating shortcuts to installed games so that my library can include games that aren't installed. Do battle.net and origin have a similar system or might there be other ways to implement this?

Comment: If it works the same way as steam, creating a shortcut on your desktop, you can open its properties and the rungameid should be found there. At least thats how it works on steam, redirecting you.

Comment: For example the steam run game id is steam://rungameid/304930 so I would assume its 304930. I got that from properties.

Comment: You are right!! I just tried it for Anno 2205 which uses `uplay://launch/1253/0`. I was hoping there would be a website like there is for steam (https://steamdb.info/). This would not require the game to be installed since you can only make shortcuts to installed games.

Comment: I suggest answering that as It did solve you problem right? (the steamdb.info site i mean) It should help others with this query.

Comment: No, because i'm looking for the steamdb.info equivalent of UPlay. Since not all UPlay games are on steam this method does not solve my specific problem.

Comment: Oh sorry. I will research this and try provide an answer.

Comment: For battle.net you can use`battlenet://xyz` where xyz stands for the short name of the game (wow, d3, wtcg, sc2,...) and for Origin it's `origin://launchgame/xyz`

Comment: @dly thanks for the information. What would be the easiest way to find 'xyz' for origin games?

Comment: maybe this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/origin/comments/3awk3q/origin_store_productid_numbers/) helps. Apparently the Origin store no longer displays them on the game overview pages. They used to be there.

Comment: @dly thanks so much. Thanks to your comment I was able to figure out all my origin games. I found battlefield 3's game id on the reddit page you sent. I used google chromes inspect element to find this game id in the origin page of battlefield 3. This showed me the id appears in a HTML attribute called offerid. This way I found the game ID's for al my origin games. I also tested the ID's using your command `origin://launchgame/{ID}`

Comment: I have also found all commands for battlenet on [this forum](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/20742815763). Except for star craft 2. The forum and @dly both suggested `battlenet://sc2` but this does not work for me. But this might be because I have the starter edition.

Comment: Nice find checking the page source :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Steam (just in case)

You can enable "Display Steam URL address bar when available" on *Steam > Settings > Interface*:

[image: Steam Parameters]

After that you will be able to see the game ID on the store page (in this case, 236870):

[image: Hitman's Store Page]

### uPlay

If you have a game shortcut on your desktop or start menu, this will contain the uPlay Game ID on the "uplay://launch/ID/0" format (in this case 54).

[image: AC3 id]

Also you can search the game ID on [Alex](https://github.com/d3adm4u5/UplayGameIDs/blob/master/latest.txt) or [Haoose](https://github.com/Haoose/UPLAY_GAME_ID/blob/master/README.md) GitHub repositories.

### Origin

Origin have game ID's, but most of the time they are not used. You can still launch the game that you want with *origin://launchgame/ID*.

To get your game ID, head down to *C:\ProgramData\Origin\LocalContent* and search for a folder called like your game:

[image: NFS:MW 2012 Folder]

Open it up and there should be 3 files that start either with "DR" or "OBF-EAST":

[image: OFB-46851 for NFS:MW 2012]

Just add : between the last word and the numbers, that is your game ID (OFB-EAST:46851). Now just use that to launch your game:

```
origin://launchgame/OFB-EAST:46851
```

You can still launch the game from the main executable for certain games:

[image: Origin Shortcut]

Just to make sure add the path of the Origin executable at the end (useful for launching the game via Steam):

```
"E:\Origin\Need for Speed(TM) Most Wanted\NFS13.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin\Origin.exe"
```

### Battle.net

The Blizzard App also does not use ID's, but you can launch them via network protocols (recommended):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Battle.net\Battle.net.exe" battlenet://GAME
```

If the app is running, you could just do:

```
battlenet://GAME
```

You need to set up the game that you want to launch on the URL:

```
World of Warcraft: WoW
Diablo III: D3
Starcraft II: SC2
Hearthstone: WTCG
Heroes of the Storm: Hero
Overwatch: Pro
Starcraft Remastered: S1
Destiny 2: DST2
Call of Duty: Black Ops 4: VIPR
```

They also can be launched via the "GameName Launcher.exe" file (for example, "Overwatch Launcher.exe") but that would require pressing play on Battle.net:

[image: Overwatch Shortcut]

Comment: If you want the uplay ID without downloading the whole game, start the installation until the download starts, you can stop immediately. Then go to the games' installation directory, there should be a `uplay_download` directory inside it. Inside that will be another directory with the game's ID as name. So assuming the default installation path for AC Unity: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Ubisoft/Ubisoft Game Launcher/games/Assassin's Creed Unity/uplay_download/720`, where the 720 is the game's ID.

Answer (score 2):

Other method for origin

Open to " installerdata.xml " in your game

"G:\Origin Games\Need for Speed(TM) Most Wanted\ __Installer"

for me

and look contentIDs

71628
    71530
    71744
    71726
    71743
    71725
    71742
    71724

For launch game

origin://launchgame/71628,71530,71744,71726,71743,71725,71742,71724

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking to find Uplay IDs of installed games.
I have created a gist here : [uPlay IDs](https://gist.github.com/sakshatshinde/a5c7a23f798fd84f094920b7e3ab1907)